# second Velocity problem

Tags: algebra-precalculus

A bus driving with a constant velocity from point A to point B, the distance between A and B is 450 km. After 2 hours, from A, a taxi achieved that bus(the taxi is also driving from A to B) the taxi velocity is bigger in 25 kph from bus velocity. The taxi continued to point B and got to B 1 hour sooner than the bus. Q: find the velocity of the bus.

I really tried to solve that, but failed.

Check my solution:

Let v be the velocity of the bus, then the distance he made is 2v.
Denote the distance that made the taxi by X, we then have X=2v.

The second equation is:

(450-X)/v = (450-X)/(v+25) + 1

And the answer is: 75 kmh

Is that right?

Answer (score 1):

Please remember that your post asked for the speed of the **bus** given all the extra information.

Meanwhile, I thought about another manner to approach the solution I provide you below :

The bus runs for T hours at a speed equal to V.
The taxi runs for (T-3) hours at a speed equal to (V+25) (the taxi started two hours after the bus and arrived  one hour earlier).
Since they run the same distance, we then have : V T = (V+25) (T-3). Substracting the lhs from the rhs and simplifying then leads to T = 3 (V / 25 + 1). In the other hand, we know that V T = 450; eliminating T leads to 450 / V =  3 (V / 25 + 1). Expanding leads to a quadratic equation which is (V^2 + 25 V - 3750); the solutions of this quadratic are V = -75 (we can discard) and V = 50 (we shall keep).

We can go further : since the bus runs 450 km at a speed of 50 km/hr, the total time spend by the bus is 450 / 50 = 9 hours. SO the taxi runs 6 hours at a speed of 75 km/hr which gives 450 km again.

If I had given this problem to my students, I would have added two questions :
1) at what time will the taxi and the bus will be at the same location ?
2) at which distance of A will that happen ?

Using the equations given in my first answer, since bus at taxi will be at the same place and the same time, we should have V T = (V+25) (T-2); replacing V by 50, we obtain T = 6 and V T = 300. Then, 300 km after A and 6 hours after the bus left A, bus and taxi will be at the same point.

Please check that **my** answer to **your** question is corresct and **confirm** or **deny** it.

Answer (score 0):

I think that the best could be to plot the distance as a function of time.

The equation for the bus is V t and for the taxi it is (V+25)(t-2) since the taxi started two hours later. Let say that T is the arrival time for the bus; so the arrival time for the taxi is (T-1).
So, when they arrived to point B, we have
V T = 450 for the bus
and
(V+25) (T-3)= 450 for the taxi.
So, you have two equations for two unknowns the solutions of which being V=50 and T=9.

I suggest you control what I tried to explain using the graph.

Comment: The answer is 75.

Comment: @user119501. If you remember V is the speed of the bus. Then 50+25=75  for the taxi. Tell me, please, if my explanations were OK for you. Cheers